# Animated gif won't loop in Safari Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

When adding gifs to my site I was fully expecting them not to loop automatically; however, on the browsers I currently have installed I am getting some very strange behaviour. For a start the gifs do not loop infinitely even when using this code:

`<img src="example.gif" dynsrc="example.gif" loop=infinite />`

However, they loop twice rather than once which confused me even more. I couldn't find anything about this online other that what's been stated above so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try recreating you gifs with something like http://gifmaker.me/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"loop" does not appear within attribute lists for IMG elements specified by any of the [HTML3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#img), [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG) or [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html) standards.

Like you I have read or seen "loop" described somewhere (and some time ago) but it does not appear to have ever been standardized.

The safest option would be to re-edit the gif files and when saving them specify a loop count of 0 (or infinite if the editor presents that as the choice). You might like to try `loop="0"` in the `IMG` tag first but as mentioned I don't think it's standard and could easily fail.